# What does the <> operator do in python?

Tags: python

I just came across this [here](http://www.feedparser.org/feedparser.py), always used like this:

```
if string1.find(string2) <> -1:
    pass
```

What does the `<>` operator do, and why not use the usual `==` or `in`?

Sorry if that has been answered before, search engines don't like punctuation.

Comment: Sites like this should have a regex-capable search engine.  Like Google Code Search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python ( or general programming ). Why use <> instead of != and are there risks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312169/python-or-general-programming-why-use-instead-of-and-are-there-risks)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin says:

> The [operators] `<>` and `!=` are equivalent; for consistency with C, `!=` is preferred. [...] The `<>` spelling is considered obsolescent.

Answer (score 7):

`<>` is the same as `!=` although [the `<>` form is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/operators.html).  Your code sample could be more cleanly be written as:

```
if string2 not in string1:
    pass
```

Comment: `not string2 in string1` would be better as `string2 not in string1`

Answer (score 0):

<> would mean greater than or less than, essentially 'not equal'.

Comment: technically less than or greater than though it's irrelevant ;)