# != vs <> in Python?

Tags: python, math, comparison

I was reading the Python docs earlier, and I discovered `<>`. How exactly does this differ from `!=`? As far as I can tell, the only difference is that `<>` won't work with strings. Does `<>` do something special that `!=` doesn't, or is there a reason I hadn't heard about it for over two years?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262638/what-does-the-operator-do-in-python/4262646#4262646

Comment: Don't use `<>`. it was removed from python 3.

Comment: Hint when searching for operators before you ask, enclose the operators in double quotes, so a search looks like `[python] "!=" "<>"`. These operator questions have always been asked before and will pop right up if searched correctly.

Answer (score 5):

`<>` is a remnant of the past. Quoting the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

> `!= can also be written <>, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use !=.`

Also, worth noting that Python 3 doesn't support `<>`.

Comment: Is it only me, or does the blockquote only appear on mouseover?

Comment: it's the same for me.

Comment: Oh, there's a `spoiler` class on it. I have not seen that around here in a while.

Comment: Fixed it. Apparently, `!` is for spoilers :)

Answer (score 2):

`<>` *exactly the same thing* as `!=`, for strings or any other type:

```
>>> 'a' <> 'b'
True
>>> 'a' != 'b'
True
```

However, `<>` is deprecated. It has been [removed from Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax). Always use `!=` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Operator `<>` is simply the deprecated verision of `!=`.

See from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/comparisons.html).