# How to use filename.find()?

Tags: python, function

I am new to python, and am trying to understand a script that has the following lines:

```
dotInd = fileName.find(".")
if dotInd <> -1:
    newFC = fileName[0:dotInd]
    outFC = newFC + "_buffer"
else:
    outFC = fileName + "_buffer"
```

I have not been able to find what fileName.find(".") is doing, and what the condition dotInd<>-1 means

(Confused about the <> thing)

Any help would be apreciated, also, is there a place where you cand find a list of what all python functions do? Thanks

Comment: *"...is there a place where you cand [sic] find a list of what all python functions do?"* - have you tried [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/)

Comment: `<>` is just the *wrong* way of writing `!=` (not equal). In python3 it doesn't work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: if you are aware that `fileName` is just the identifier, not the type, sure.

Answer (score 5):

`fileName` is an identifier, and refers to an object of type *`str`*. You are looking for [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find). The method returns `-1` if the sought-after text is not found, a position otherwise.

`<>` is an [archaic and deprecated way of spelling `!=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312169/python-or-general-programming-why-use-instead-of-and-are-there-risks), so it tests if the `'.'` has been found; if so, the returned position is used to slice the string, removing everything from the `'.'` to the end.

The code could be better written as:

```
outFC = fileName.partition('.')[0] + '_buffer'
```

which will result in the same output without `str.find()` and testing the output. See the [`str.partition()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) documentation for more information.

It would be more correct still to use [`os.path.splitext()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to prevent splitting on a *leading* `.` (signifying a hidden file on POSIX systems):

```
import os.path

outFC = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0] + '_buffer'
```